# REST API azure speech to text (RECOGNIZED: Text=undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, api, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the azure api (speech to text), but when I execute the code it does not give me the audio result.
The audio is in the format requested (.WAV).

code example documentation

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("---", "eastus2");

function fromFile() {
    let pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();

    fs.createReadStream("audio/aboutSpeechSdk.wav").on('data', function (arrayBuffer) {
        pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.slice());
    }).on('end', function () {
        pushStream.close();
    });

    let audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
    let recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
        console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`);
        recognizer.close();
    });
}

fromFile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you provide, it seems that you do not configure Speech Recognition Language. Please add the code `speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = ""` into you sample. For more details about language, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#speech-to-text)

For example. You can download the [video](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/66d7131368ce53b333e13416428996b023be88cc/sampledata/audiofiles/aboutSpeechSdk.wav) to do a test.

```
var sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
var fs = require("fs");
var subscriptionKey = "";
var serviceRegion = "";
var language = "en-US";

function openPushStream(filename) {
  // create the push stream we need for the speech sdk.
  var pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();

  // open the file and push it to the push stream.
  fs.createReadStream(filename)
    .on("data", function (arrayBuffer) {
      pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.slice());
    })
    .on("end", function () {
      pushStream.close();
    });

  return pushStream;
}

var audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(
  openPushStream("aboutSpeechSdk.wav")
);
var speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
  subscriptionKey,
  serviceRegion
);
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = language;
var recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
  function (result) {
    console.log(result.text);
    recognizer.close();
    recognizer = undefined;
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    recognizer.close();
    recognizer = undefined;
  }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://nbellocam.dev/blog/speech-to-text/)